# Something simpler/better than ConfigurationSection, ConfigurationElement, and ConfigurationElementCollection?

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config

This way of configuring is great as it allows you to define whats required, and even add validators to your config.

However it's one big pain once you start mapping anything more complex than element with attributes or a collection of simple elements !

Haven't they come out with something simpler like just creating a Class/Model and mapping that directly to a config section with validation and all, or has someone come up with a simpler solution ?

For example for this i went as far as giving up on ConfigurationSection and implemented it with xml & xsd validation ..but i'm not happy about it

Actually at first (after giving up on ConfigurationSection ) i tried to implement it as a ViewModel with DataAnnotations but that brought about it's own problems when calling the validate method without being in a controller context, and validating nested models...

```
[XmlRoot("Configuration", Namespace = "urn:Configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlElement("Common")]
    public Common Common { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FaceBook")]
    public FaceBook FaceBook { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Domains")]
    public List<Domain> Domains { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Links")]
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Common
{
    [XmlAttribute("analyticsId")]
    public string AnalyticsId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("analyticsDomain")]
    public string AnalyticsDomain { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("segmentationId")]
    public int SegmentationId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("serviceId")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
}

public class FaceBook
{
    [XmlAttribute("apiKey")]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("appId")]
    public long AppId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("canvas")]
    public string Canvas { get; set; }
}

public class Replacement
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Domain
{
    [XmlAttribute("host")]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("culture")]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("paymentRequired")]
    public bool PaymentRequired { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("paymentDocumentId")]
    public int PaymentDocumentId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("paymentTimeout")]
    public int PaymentTimeout { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("default")]
    public bool Default { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Replacements")]
    public List<Replacement> Replacements { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("AgeRange")]
    public List<AgeRange> AgeRanges { get; set; }
}

public class AgeRange
{
    [XmlAttribute("ageMin")]
    public int AgeMin { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ageMax")]
    public int AgeMax { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("botPercentage")]
    public int BotPercentage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("genderPercentage")]
    public int GenderPercentage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("anonymousDomain")]
    public string AnonymousDomain { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("certifiedDomain")]
    public string CertifiedDomain { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Salon")]
    public List<Salon> Salons { get; set; }
}

public class Salon
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("default")]
    public bool Default { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("optGroup")]
    public string OptGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I'd love to use something like ConfigurationSection with DataAnnotation for validation, but for the above example it's just overcomplicated.

Anyone find/know something simpler, while still being able to validate the correctness of the Model ?

Thanks